# error in R: Error in paste("CO", period) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm getting an error in my R program that says: Error in paste0("CO", period) :
cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
Here's my code, I can't figure out where it's coming from

```
        COdata <- COdata %>%   
          filter(!is.na(ID)) %>%
          mutate(key = paste("CO", period)) %>%
          select(-latitude, -longitude, -period, -str.month,
                 -str.day, -str.year, -end.month, -end.day, -end.year, -distance2,
                 -stations2, -days2) %>%
        spread(key = key, value = CO.concentration)
```

What's odd is that when I run the first 4 commands, the COdata is perfectly fine and the paste function creates the values that I want. However, when I run all 5 commands, then the error pops up saying that it's with the paste function.

Comment: It's because `period` is in fact a function, and it can't be used as a string.

Answer (score 0):

We would need a sample from `COdata` to answer for sure, but it seems that at the time when you run this line, `COdata` does not include a `period` column.

Therefore, R searches for an external object to paste, and the first it encounters is a function, probably `lubridate::period()`, hence the surprising error message.

To avoid this kind of "wrong" message, you could use the `dplyr` pronoun `.data`, which explicitly asks to search the variable inside the data.

Here is an example:

```
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts=FALSE)
library(lubridate, warn.conflicts=FALSE)
iris %>% mutate(key=paste("a", period))
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `key`.
#> x cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
#> i Input `key` is `paste("a", period)`.
iris %>% mutate(key=paste("a", .data$period))
#> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `key`.
#> x Column `period` not found in `.data`
#> i Input `key` is `paste("a", .data$period)`.

#Created on 2020-08-21 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```

With the `.data` pronoun, the error message is explicit, there is no column `period` not found in `.data`.